# Understanding とは言えないものが

Tags: meaning

> つまり、あまり一般的な好みとは言えないものが、お好きな方を指す言葉のようですが・・・・

There’s this sentence that I found in the internet. I can kind of understand that the later part means, “it appears to be a word to refer to people who like such things” But I’m so confused with the part before that especially “とは言えないものが”.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the sentence by words like this:

> あまり/一般的な/好み/と/は/言え/ない/**もの/が**

- 言えない - can't say
- もの(=物) - things
- が - (subject marker)

So that basically means, "I mean, it appears to be a word to refer to people whose taste differs from general ones."